# Adding RelativeLayout in to the Collapsing toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to use `RelativeLayout` in my `collapsingToolbar` . but RelativeLayout doesn't show correctly . I want add RelativeLayout under the Toolbar like this picture :

[image]

This is my xml of DetailActivity :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_detail"
                    android:layout_width="96dp"
                    android:layout_height="124dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_hamburger"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_name_detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="نام :"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_detail"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_detail"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_count_detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="تعداد"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_detail"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_name_detail"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_last_update_detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="آخرین آپدیت"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_detail"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_count_detail"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout_detail_activity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_detail_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And This code doing like this :

[image]

And I want add RelativeLayout under the toolbar.

Comment: I ma getting this from the above layout : http://imgur.com/1q8cbNM .

Comment: can you scroll these layout ??!!!

Comment: What do I have to scroll?

Comment: @majid Dude, I will be very grateful to you if you say how to do it)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I've exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the toolbar as the second view in your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.Also add `android:marginTop="your toolbar height"` to your `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link. create your tab with viewpager then pin that to collapsing app bar [click here](http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/)

Answer (score 0):

try placing the

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
```

tag outside the AppBarLayout

Comment: use comment section to suggest author.